# What's the very first method called in a view?

Tags: iphone

.....this is kind of linked to another question I have on here!
I have some code which I want to execute to update some button and label positions before the load views.
I need to check the orientation and then move the items so that they are in position before the view loads......any ideas guys?

Thanks,

Gaz.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this on `viewWillAppear` method.

For example to check orientation I use code like this..

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

     if( [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight )
    {
      self.view=self.landscapeView;
      NSLog(@"View Will Appear Land");

   }
    else
  {
      self.view = self.portraitView;

      NSLog(@"View Will Appear Port");

    }
}
```

Comment: .....that's exactly what I was looking for!....thanks sooooo much. I'm gonna give that a go! So it's the ViewWillAppear method that gets called before the view loads.....ahhhh. People have mentioned this but I wasn't sure how to implement it. Many many thanks!

Comment: .....WOO HOO!.....anonymous.....you're a legend. I can't thank you enough for helping. Without guys like you, most of us struggle and lose faith......cheers dude!.....Gaz.

Comment: Ohh.. I am no legend mate..I am just a developer started iPhone 10 months ago.. Real legends, intelligent fellows are here: http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all

Comment: You still helped me out of a spot mate. It was twisting my melon!

Answer (score 0):

viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html